# stsadm -o. What does the -o mean?

Tags: backup, command-line-interface, sharepoint

I am working on a large SharePoint farm, mainly with the backend SQL Servers. We have always used stsadm -o for all stsadm functions, but no one seems to know why. I can't seem to find the info specific for stsadm, would it be general Windows command-line sytax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The -o is short for -operation.  It basically specifies the operation of the command.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261956.aspx

Comment: Interesting I didn't een make the correlation until I re-read the technet article linked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

actually **-o[peration] operationname** distinguishes actual commands from **-help operationname** requests